# gedit can't recognize character encoding, but gvim can

Tags: gedit, gvim, utf-8, ascii

I have a lot of plain text files which come from a Windows environment.
Many of them use a whacky default Windows code-page, which is neither ASCII (7 bits) nor UTF-8.

**gvim** has no problem opening these files, but **gedit** fails to do so.
**gvim** reports the encoding as **latin1**.

I assume that **gvim** is making a "smart" assumption about the code-page.
(I believe this code-page still has international **variants**).

Some questions arise from this:

- (1). Is there some way the **gedit** can be told to recoginze this code-page?
  ** **NB.** [Update] For this point (1), see **my** answer, below.
  **         For points (2) and (3). see Oli's answer.
- (2). Is there a way to scan the file system to identify these problem files?
- (3).  Is there a batch converting tool to convert these files to UTF-8?

(.. this old-world text mayhem was actually the final straw which brought me over to Ubuntu... UTF-8 system-wide by default ***Brilliant***)

**[UPDATE]**
  ** **NB:** ** *I now consider the following Update to be partially irrelevent, because the "problem" files aren't the "problem" (see **my** answer below).

I've left it here, because is may be of some general use to someone.*

---

I've worked out a rough and ready way to identify the problem files...
The `file` command was not suitable, because it identified my example file as ASCII... but an ASCII file is 100% UTF-8 compliant...

As I mentioned in a comment below, the test for an invalid **first** byte of a UTF-8 codepoint is:

- *if the first byte (of a UTF-8 codepoint) is between 0x80 and 0xBF (reserved for additional bytes), or greater than 0xF7 ("overlong form"), that is considered an error*

I know `sed` (a bit, via a Win32 port), so I've managed to cobble together a RegEx pattern which finds these **offending** bytes.

It's an ugly line, so look away now if **regular expressions** scare you :)

I'd really appreciate it if someone points out how to use **hex** values in a **range []** expression.. I've just used the **or** operator **\|**

```
fqfn="/my/fully/qualified/filename"  
sed -n "/\x80\|\x81\|\x82\|\x83\|\x84\|\x85\|\x86\|\x87\|\x88\|\x89\|\x8A\|\x8B\|\x8C\|\x8D\|\x8E\|\x8F\|\x90\|\x91\|\x92\|\x93\|\x94\|\x95\|\x96\|\x97\|\x98\|\x99\|\x9A\|\x9B\|\x9C\|\x9D\|\x9E\|\x9F\|\xA0\|\xA1\|\xA2\|\xA3\|\xA4\|\xA5\|\xA6\|\xA7\|\xA8\|\xA9\|\xAA\|\xAB\|\xAC\|\xAD\|\xAE\|\xAF\|\xB0\|\xB1\|\xB2\|\xB3\|\xB4\|\xB5\|\xB6\|\xB7\|\xB8\|\xB9\|\xBA\|\xBB\|\xBC\|\xBD\|\xBE\|\xBF\|\xF8\|\xF9\|\xFA\|\xFB\|\xFC\|\xFD\|\xFE\|\xFF/p" "${fqfn}"
```

So, I'll now graft this into **Oli's** batch solution... Thanks Oli!

PS.  Here is the invalid UTF-8 byte it found in my sample file ...
**"H.Bork, Gøte-borg."**  ... the **"ø"** = **F8 hex**... which is an invalid UTF-8 character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`iconv` is probably what you'll want to use. `iconv -l` will show you the available encodings and then you can use a couple of commands to recode them all:

```
# all text files are in ./originals/
# new files will be written to ./newversions/

mkdir -p newversions
cd originals
for file in *.txt; do
    cat $file | iconv -f ASCII -t utf-8 > ../newversions/$file;
done
```

If you want to do this with files you don't the encoding of (because they're all over the place), you want to bring in a few more commands: `find`, `file`, `awk` and `sed`. The last two are just there to process the output of file.

```
for file in find . -type f -exec file --mime {} \; | grep "ascii" | awk '{print $1}' | sed s/.$//; do
    ...
```

I've no idea if this actually works so I certainly wouldn't run it from anything but the least important directory you have (make a testing folder with some known ASCII files in). The syntax of find might preclude it from being within a for loop. I'd hope that somebody else with more bash experience could jump in there and sort it out so it does the right thing.

Comment: Aha thanks; that sorts out the batch encoding.. I actually used a Win32 port of **iconv** a couplo of years ago, to convert between UTF-8 and UTF-16... I thought it was only for conversion between different unicode encodings, but as you've pointed out, it does **much** more....  Do you know of any way to actually **find** these files? They are scattered over many many directories...

Comment: You'd want to expand the script to use `find` (to find all .txt files) and its `-exec` flag to run something against that file. Then you'd want the `file` command to detect the charset. Hang on a minute. I'll edit my answer to show you what I'm thinking.

Comment: I tried `file`, but it returns ASCII...  I think this is what I need to detect ... `If the first byte (of a UTF-8 codepoint) is between 0x80 and 0xBF (reserved for additional bytes), or greater than 0xF7 ("overlong form"), that is considered an
error`

Answer (score 1):

Gedit can detect the correct character set only if it is listed at "File-Open-Character encoding".
You can alter this list but keep in mind that the order is important.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the 3 command lines :

```
gedit --encoding=utf-8 filename
gedit --encoding=iso-8859-15 filename
gedit --encoding=utf-16 filename
. . . . .
```

Comment: thanks it works but it doesn't solve the problem if you are not using the terminal

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about this a bit more...

Yes, the "ø" = 0xF8 hex* was definitely the reason why **gedit** would not open the file...
Why? Because it is not a valid UTF-8 byte.
By default, **gedit** will only open UTF-8 files...

However, **gedit** does have a codepage auto-detect feature, but you must first **Add** codepages to its list of "possibles".

The bright red dialog which appears when **gedit** can't recognize the code-page, has a buttone on it which allows you to **Add** another codepage...

Problem solved!... **almost** ...

The knarly issue now raise its head again.... Which codepage is it?

In my situation, I can reasolably assume that it is the standard English Windows codepage (for my region?, or for the region of the file's origin? .. I did mention "knarly" :)....

Anyhow, **gedit** will allow you to load a file once you have **Added** the codepage to its list...

So, although all the Terminal commands are useful and interesting in their own right, it seems that that line of thought was heading up the wrong track.

There is nothing intrinsicly **wrong** in these files...
The issue seems to be purely about codepages.

**gedit** can open the file, just as **gvim** can.
...but the relevant codepage must first be **Added** to its codepage list.
eg. via th File-Open dialog, or the red warning dialog I encounterd.

Comment: in case you don't have a clue, is there any way to "detect" from the terminal which codepage you need?

Comment: Trying to establish which codepage was intended by the original author is not possible in many situations. Sub-sets of several codepages often coincide and produce a "valid" state (for that codepage and that text). The matching codepage can be *technically* valid, but text may show as the wrong symbol.  In these cases, it really requires that the text be proof-read by a person!

Comment: Regarding ways to detect the codepage via the terminal; `iconv` and `recode` can be used, but it is clumsy, as there are often multiple "valid" possibilities. You need to just keep testing codepages (valid and invalid) until you find a *technically* valid codepage...  I just use `emacs` instead... which, by the way, is scriptable. ie. You can call emac's *elisp* scripting language from a *bash* script (just as you may call *awk*).